# How is bacterial plasma membrane made?

Tags: cell-biology, bacteriology, enzymes, cell-membrane, prokaryotes

Eukaryotes have ER which manufactures plasma membrane of cells. How is prokaryotic plasma membrane made ? What is the pathway and which enzymes are involved ?

Answer (score 1):

The processes that occur at the ER membrane in eukaryotic cells take place directly at the bacterial plasma membrane. Phospholipids are synthesised and inserted at the plasma membrane, and there is a protein translocation apparatus for translocation of proteins into the periplasmic space and insertion of transmembrane proteins into the plasma membrane.

Comment: Thank you Alan. It would be nice if you could add some more detail.